# Livewire: persist custom objects in Livewire component after wire:click?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Can I keep using a collection of custom objects throughout a Livewire lifecycle?
I create a collection, show them in a list, and take action when the user selects one.

At the moment they are still an object in the blade `@foreach` (i.e. `{{ $item->name }}`, but end up as array after the `wire:click` (i.e. `$item['name']`), which breaks running the same `@foreach` again after completing the `wire:click` method.

But more importantly, each custom object contains a collection of models and they are converted to plain array as well.

It seems this is currently [expected behavior](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/2728) as Livewire does not know how to rehydrate them (unlike Eloquent models).

I was hoping that I could store the objects in protected property but these do not persist, [just like the documentation says](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties).

Is there a way to achieve a similar flow where I display a list (using data from custom objects) and take action on the selected custom object?

Answer (score 0):

`protected` properties truly are only useful for variables that are consistent, such as rules, or variables that are set each request that cannot be public.

As for the collection issue, it seems like the answer is already in the github issue thread you linked, by simply re-initiating the arrays as object. It (for now) is expected behaviour as it cannot rehydrate. You can do a map on the collection:

```php
$this->customCollection = $this->customCollection->map(function($item) {
    return is_array($item) ? (object) $item : $item;
});
```

or a foreach like so:

```php
foreach ($this->customCollection as $index => $item) {
    if (is_array($item)) {
        $this->customCollection[$index] = (object) $item;
    }
}
```

For each nest of collections, you'll have to do the same looping if you specifically want custom objects. It'll probably lose out on performance and you're probably better off using Eloquent collections/models or pure arrays.

Comment: Thanks Yinci, the answer in the referred issue is indeed fine as a workaround for simple standard class objects, but would require a custom "rehydrate" action to rehydrate each of the Laravel model collections in the custom object. Was wondering if there is a smart way to "store" the custom object collection. Now exploring: caching the collection and retrieve it on every action.

Comment: I hadn't thought about caching. Caching is a great option if you really need the custom collection. Any reasoning as to why Eloquent won't work in your situation?

Comment: Caching is indeed doing the job. :-)  I do analysis on the Eloquent Models and create custom objects (e.g. reverse geocode results based on latlon Trackpoint coordinates, grouped by visits). Only after user selects one of the suggestions the place is converted to a Laravel Model and linked to visit Trackpoints.

Comment: I suppose the analysis is relatively complex? Otherwise having it as mutator attribute could also fix the problem? (Haven't tried this). Anyhow, glad to hear caching is working.

Comment: Yes, the analysis is complex and "expensive" as it requires REST API calls to external services.